# Laravel 5.2.32: Session flash doesn't work with redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, middleware

I have a controller which has a redirect function:

```
public function myControllerMethod() 
{
    $data = $this->blabla();

    return Redirect::to('previousroute')->with('data', $data);
}
```

This previousroute is handled by otherControllerMethod() like so:

```
public function otherControllerMethod()
{
    $data = Session::get('data');

    return $this->makeView($data);
}
```

Unfortunately, Laravel forgets this session data. I've done this many times before and I have never seen if forget the session flash data after a single redirect. What is going on here? I have tried both adding and removing "web" middleware but nothing works. If anyone knows why this happens let me know.

Comment: I've experienced a similar issue a couple of times. Can you check if the problem is that you are getting a new session each request? In my case the problem was related to Varnish. Varnish was not bypassing a cookie to ngnix which turned out into a new session each time. There are a couple of workaround in that case: tweaking your varnish setup or adding a special header to force varnish to bypass cookies. Hope it bring some light.

Comment: None of the code you've shown sets any session or flash data.

Comment: patricus - that is actually not true. A redirect() using the with() method does flash data. See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 2):

```
use Session;

public function myControllerMethod() 
{
    $data = $this->blabla();
    Session::set('data', $data);
    return Redirect::to('previousroute')->with('data', $data);
}

public function otherControllerMethod()
{
    $data = Session::get('data');

    return $this->makeView($data);
}
```

Try like this. Use the session and set the data in session and get it from where you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same Issue before. Basically I needed to call `send` function when redirecting using `Redirect` facade. So you need to change your `myControllerMethod` to:

```
public function myControllerMethod() 
{
    $data = $this->blabla();
    return Redirect::to('previousroute')->with('data', $data)->send();
}
```

As `send()` function of class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` calls the function `sendContent()` which sends the data when redirecting.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `myControllerMethod` you are passing the `data` obj/var as a Request.

In `otherControllerMethod` you are requesting the Session data which is not set.

In order to put data to the session you should do:

```
Session::put('data','value')
```

and then it will be available with:

```
Session::get('data');
```